# Can't compile #pragma omp task depend

Tags: c, dependencies, task, openmp

When I compile this code with gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>

long result=0;

void foo() {
#pragma omp parallel 
    { 


    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,3) 
    for (long i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      #pragma omp task shared(result) depend(in:result) depend(out:result)
      {
          result++;
      }
      #pragma omp task depend(in: result)
          result++;
      }

   #pragma omp taskwait
   printf("result = %ld\n", result);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   foo();
  printf("result = %ld\n", result);
}`
```

this message appears

> test_task_name.c: In function ‘foo’:
>
> test_task_name.c:18:34: error: expected ‘#pragma omp’ clause before ‘depend’
>     #pragma omp task shared(result) depend(in:result) depend(out:result)
>                                     ^
>
> test_task_name.c:21:19: error: expected ‘#pragma omp’ clause before ‘depend’
>     #pragma omp task depend(in: result)

I'm using this Make file to compile my OpenMP aplication:

```
.SUFFIXES: -gomp  -gasm
CC = gcc
OPENMP     = -fopenmp
CFLAGS   = -Wall -O -std=c99 -march=native -I.

.c-gasm:
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPENMP) -c -S $< -o $@

.c-gomp: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPENMP) $< -o $@
```

Comment: What version of GCC are you using? Task dependencies are part of OpenMP 4.0, which is only supported in GCC 4.9 or newer.

Comment: Thanks I've updated my gcc to the 4.9 version and it works!